# Why is text not vertically-centered beside an image in a div?

Tags: html

I need to move an image and text in the `div` with "My Text Left" as shown in the picture below, and vertically center the text beside the image in the `div`.

http://jsfiddle.net/gdWM5/22/

This is what I've got:

[image]

This is what I want please :)

[image]

Comment: can you share the expected output image? little hard to understand your question

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan "My Text Left" is not in middle of div @ fiddle

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/gdWM5/25/?

Comment: do you want like this http://jsfiddle.net/gdWM5/26/

Comment: @Beginner nope, does it look like what i want in question ? :(

Comment: There are two parts to your question, and I show code, a screenshot, and both fixes for you below.

Comment: @digitalextremist thanks, +1, going to try now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use margins... ( on the `<div>` element )

```
.mLogoTextClass { 
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 0px; /* Here you go */
}
```

## ... and `align="absmiddle"` ( on the `<img>` )

```
<img align="absmiddle" src="http://www.shark-helmets.com/images/bases/youtube-logo.jpg" />
```

### **JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/gdWM5/29/

[image]

Comment: Thanks but text is still not in middle :(

Answer (score 0):

*You can't vertically align a block elements*.  You have use it as **`table-cell`**

```
.mFirstClass {
    width:100%; 
    height: 20%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    display: inline-table;  // changed here
}

.mLogoTextClass { 
    position:relative; //change position to relative
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    right:0;
    display: table-cell; //added it
    top:0;
}
```

### [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdWM5/30/)